# How can I get the bytecodes that are executed at runtime for a Java program?

Tags: java, debugging, bytecode

The compiled .class file contains bytecodes corresponding to whole java class. However, during execution, some bytecodes are exectued multiple times while some are probably not executed at all, depending on the logic and the input. Is there a way that I could get a trace of only those bytecodes that are *executed* during the lifetime of the java program?

**Edit: Use case**

I think a use-case may help. After a sample run of the program, I would like to count the frequency of the bytecode instructions that were executed (e.g. areturn has been carried out 10 times). Is there a profiler or any other tool that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Have you tried a profiler?

Comment: you could look at the EMMA code coverage tool (or other similar instrumentation libraries). It can integrate with IDEs and show you at a source level, which lines of code were executed and which are not.

Comment: Agree with both the above points. Pulling a full trace -- if you could find an instrumented JVM that would do it for you -- would run terribly slowly and produce a HUGE logfile which would be terribly slow to analyze. Code coverage tools which show you which sections of your program are executing how often are much faster. Statistical profilers, especially those which can be focused on specific periods of runtime, theoretically are less precise but since they disrupt execution time less they may actually be significantly more accurate, especially in multithreaded code.

Comment: Java has [built-in instrumentation facilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) that will, in theory, allow you to collect this information.  Plus lots of IDEs and other development tools support this to one degree or another.

Comment: In practice, the JVM usually compiles to native code and executes that, so it's not really meaningful to ask which bytecodes it's executing. If you don't care about that or about performance, then you could always just try using an instrumented interperter.

Comment: @Antimony - Correct, sort of.  Standard profilers will be set up to inhibit JIT compilation if that's necessary to achieve the necessary profiling.

Comment: Just run `java -Xprof …`

Answer (score 1):

this obscure paper talks about such a tool

http://ccsl.icmc.usp.br/files/vincenzi-et-al-2003.pdf

it's quite old (2003)

it states

> This paper describes a coverage testing tool for Java programs and Java-based components, named JaBUTi
>   (Java Bytecode Understanding and Testing). Differently from other testing tools that require 
>   the Java source code to carry out the program analysis, instrumentation and coverage assessment, 
>   our tool requires only the Java bytecode. Bytecode can be viewed as an assembly-like language that 
>   retains high-level information about a program [Lindholm and Yellin, 1999 ]. 
>   Therefore, JaBUTi enables the user to test Java programs and Java-based components even when no 
>   source code is available. There are others testing tools that work at the bytecode level. 
>   The frame work JUnit [Beck and Gamma, 2002 ], for instance, can be used to test Java bytecode, but 
>   it only enables performing black-box testing; it does not report any coverage information. 
>   JTest [Corporation, 2002] and GlassJAR [Edge, 2002 ] provide coverage information with respect 
>   to control-flow testing criteria at the bytecode level, but none of them supports dataflow coverage 
>   testing criteria. By working at the bytecode level we want to provide a tool that can be used 
>   for testing not only Java applications that have the corresponding source code available, but also, 
>   the ones that have only the bytecode, like software components